# Windows 10 hotspot on usb wifi with 5GHz

Tags: windows-10, wireless-networking, hotspot

I wanted to create 5GHz network from my laptop using external USB Wifi dongle. Area im in is crowded in 2.4 Ghz, so hotspoting wia internal adapter is not an option. Is there any ways to specify adaptor/frequency? My OS Windows is 10.0.17763, USB adapter is Realtec 8811CU based.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: There is no common way to do what you need except open WiFi device driver's property and change Frequency there. On Windows each WiFi driver has own implementation for changing its property.

Comment: @MikePetrichenko but built in hotspot does not detect another network card and does not create even 2.4 mode hotspot, when internal is swiched off.

Comment: Try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23168152/use-netsh-wlan-set-hostednetwork-to-create-a-wifi-hotspot-and-the-authenti

Comment: @MikePetrichenko it is actualy helped, with drivers forced to ac mode. If somebody point out app that can do same without disabling main adapter it will be nice.

Comment: Unfortunately on Windows its not possible because Hosted Network API does not allow to specify adapter on which it must start. So disabling the only way. However you can disable it from an application if needed.